# Logging Operations

Tags: c#, logging, ms-word

I've made a program in c# that solves Engineering Economy problems, such as finding the present value of an investment, or the future / payment, number of periods, rate of interest, B/C analysis, Present Worth Analysis, Bonds, etc.

The issue I have right now is that I want to save the operations I've made in a Microsoft Word file, and have the formulas nicely formatted with Microsoft Word's Equation Editor.

Right now I'm just saving the information to a text file with methods like this one.

```
public async void LogFV(decimal i, decimal n, decimal p, decimal pmt, decimal res)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(FileName, true))
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("Given Data: ");
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("i = {0:P}", i));
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("n = {0}", n));
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("A = {0:C}", pmt));
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("P = {0:C}", p));
        sb.AppendLine("Resolution: ");
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("F = {0} * (F/P, {1:P}, {2}) + {3} * (F/A, {1:P}, {2})", p, i, n, pmt));
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("F = {0:C}", res));

        await writer.WriteLineAsync(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

I don't want to re-invent the wheel, this isn't homework. Right now I thought of using the Online LaTeX equation editor but I prefer Microsoft Word's editor.

A design pattern question that I also want to ask is, how should I implement the Logger? I don't want to have it mixed in with the implementation for the Formulas, so I thought about creating a Logger class that delegates to the specific formula (e.g FV, PV, etc) and performs the logging tasks with the parameters. But I think there must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: There is an Office COM library for this very purpose ( to create, write, and save a word file ).

Comment: If you want to write some WordDocument with the formulas as logging output this should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx. It's quite easy to produce a word document with that library.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I'll check out Open XML. Thanks for the link, paiden